# How to use an exec command in TCL to invoke a shortcut file?

Tags: tcl, shortcut-file

I have a wrapper written in TCL for automating our application. So we basically invoke the exe (exec <app.exe>) and continue testing, as simple as that. Due to cybersecurity issues, we now have only a shortcut available as part of the installation. So 2 things now, either I have to invoke a shortcut (.lnk) to launch the application or invoke the exe from the source path (it is a javaw command with a chain of arguments). In both cases I get the error, No file or directory. I read lot of previous answers and tried multiple options, autoexec, eval, adding all the arguments in list etc., But javaw+jar location and script location is all different and it is getting extremely tricky. Is there a way to invoke a shortcut from tcl? I tried this in bat, cmd.exe /c <app.lnk> and it works. I tried the same in exec, doesn't work. I invoked bat file from exec, doesn't work! Any pointers please? Am desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Try `exec cmd /c path/to/app.lnk`

Or better

```
exec {*}[auto_execok start] "" [file nativename path/to/app.lnk]
```

See https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/start

Comment: Hey thanks! But in both cases I get the error popup, ''app.lnk. The specified path does not exist. Check the path and try again" and in the command prompt I see, "The system cannot find the file app.lnk". I navigated to path of the app, passed the path name to the file command, still get the error.. What else am I missing?

Comment: Well, do you know where the `app.lnk` file is?

Comment: Well yes. Am trying to execute this command from the app.lnk path in command prompt. I tried passing the path also

Comment: Can someone help please!!! Am really desperate.

Comment: I suggest you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- saying "I tried this and that" is not as helpful as showing the code your have, what your input is, what the actual output is and how that differs from your expected output. I'm sorry you're feeling desparate, but you can improve your question to get better help.

Comment: @glennjackman I understand what you are saying. While invoking the shortcut, this is all the error I get (sorry I couldn’t attach image for some reason).
//C:\Program Files\6.33>tclsh
% exec {*}[auto_execok start] "" [file nativename "app.lnk"]
The system cannot find the file app.lnk.
I also get a popup error, ''app.lnk. The specified path does not exist. Check the path and try again"

Comment: After multiple tries, I finally figured out the command to invoke the actual exe,
//"javaw -DDaoPackageName=sql -Dcom.a.b.initInfo="C:\ProgramData\6.33\dependencies\ f1zrLkuxatEZ1MMxEVTcpzZDfiqZFv5zgKRsdxPv" -jar x.jar" 
This command opens the application but when I tried in tcl,

Comment: C:\Program Files\ICU Medical MedNet Meds 6.33>tclsh
%
% set command "javaw -DDaoPackageName=sql -Dcom.hospira.mednet.initInfo=\"C:\\ProgramData\\6.33\\dependencies\\f1zrLkuxatEZ1MMxEVTcpzZDfiqZFv5zgKRsdxPv\" -jar x.jar"
javaw -DDaoPackageName=sql -Dcom.hospira.mednet.initInfo="C:\ProgramData\6.33\dependencies\f1zrLkuxatEZ1MMxEVTcpzZDfiqZFv5zgKRsdxPv" -jar x.jar
%
%
%
% exec {*}$command
Error: Could not find or load main class Medical
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Medical
%

Comment: There is no class called Medical as far as I know. If this is complicated, invoking the shortcut is pretty straight forward and am wondering why that throws an error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try creating the command as a list: `set command [list javaw -DDaoPackageName=sql {-Dcom.hospira.mednet.initInfo=C:\\ProgramData\\6.33\\dependencies\\f1zrLkuxatEZ1MMxEVTcpzZDfiqZFv5zgKRsdxPv} -jar x.jar]` -- then see what `exec {*}$command` does.

Comment: @glennjackman It works!!! The application opens now. Thanks a ton!